# What's wrong with my code that extracts the frames from a video in my online cluster?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Each video is 4 minutes in length. There are 10 files in the folder, and I want to do it all together. I am using a cluster, not a PC. I am trying to save them in the Untitled folder.

```
data_path=".."
videos = ["{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 10)]
videos_path = ["../X {}.mov".format(data_path, video) for video in videos]
count=1
for vid in videos_path:
    vid = r"{}/X {}.mov"+vid
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)
    def getFrame(sec):
        vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,sec*1000)
        hasFrames,image = vidcap.read()
        if hasFrames:
            cv2.imwrite("{}/Untitled Folder/"+str(count)+".jpg", image) # Save frame as JPG file
        return hasFrames
    sec = 0
    frameRate = 300 # Change this number to 1 for each 1 second
   
    success = getFrame(sec)
    while success:
        count = count + 1
        sec = sec + frameRate
        sec = round(sec,300)
        success = getFrame(sec)
```

Comment: Remember that range(1,10) gives you 1 through 9.  And you are formatting things way too many times.  The elements in "videos_path" will be "../X 1.mov" and "../X 2.mov" (with a space in the name -- is that really what you wanted?).  And you are passing two things to that "format" call, but you only have one placeholder.  Then, in your loop, you are mangling so vid will be "{}/X {}.mov../X {}.mov", which is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Let's put it another way.  What, EXACTLY, do you want the file names to be?

Comment: Hello, I actually want them to be renamed from 1 to n count(for all the videos), and I want them to be saved in a particular folder. I mean I just want to read all the videos in a go, then from X 1..... X n whatever maybe the number of images generated for all 10 videos.

Comment: I mean I just want them as X 1.jpg, X 2.jpg...... upto n times